# Best way to download stream from Azure Blob Storage

Tags: c#, .net, azure, stream, azure-blob-storage

I've got azure blob storage premium/hot.

I saved a blob file with size 14.43 MiB.

Now in c# im trying save this file to stream but it takes 7-9 seconds. I've tried many methods but result is always the same. For me it's very long and maybe it's better way to do that.
I'm trying write this stream to Responde.Bodywriter.

How i'm dealing with download stream:

```
using (var fileStream = await blobContainerClient.GetBlobBaseClient(blobName).OpenReadAsync())
      {
        await fileStream.CopyToAsync(request.HttpResponse.BodyWriter.AsStream(true));
      }
```

Is there any way to boost this operation?

I read somewhere that i can set StreamMinimumReadSizeInBytes (default is 4MB) but i don't know it's helps and i can't find where to do that.

Comment: Have you tried, how long it takes to download the file through browser on Azure Portal? I have already seen sometimes, that an upload of a file to azure blob storage was lighting fast and a download was some kind of throttled from Azure site, but I could reproduce the slow download on different machines (networks) by using the Azure portal. So the bottleneck (or throttling) was on the Microsoft site.

Comment: I have probably problem with CopyToAsync operation. It takes a huge amount of time.

Comment: I use the CloudBlockBlob assembly which gives you the ability to retrieve and upload (from memory or file)

Comment: If your download is slow, it must not be a problem of your code. Maybe its your network or even Azure. Easiest way to test is by trying to download through browser and Azure portal. If this is not much faster then your tries, the problem is on the Azure or network side and you can't program anything to improve it.

Comment: It's not a problem probably with download. Download stream takes like 0.1 s and copy it to another stream takes 7-8 sec :/

Comment: Does the code sample here helps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/89440/getting-very-slow-speed-while-downloading-storage.html ?

Comment: I think initiating connection with Azure takes some time. To test if this is the issue, download the file twice in MemoryStream, and observe if second download will finish fast.